# building criteria for mongodb query

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor

I need to be able to contact different field values , to build my final mongoDB query params in a dynamic way , sort of a criteria building .
is there a way to do that with meteor or just javascript ? 
assuming user has a department field in profile , shift in profile , how can cumulate several params to have in my final query at the end of the loop .

```
   criteria= {}
   rules.each(function(rule){
        rule.RulesSet.each(function(subRule){
            if(subRule.type="equals"){
                switch (subRule.code){
                    case 'department':
                        critera.department =subRule.value;
                    case 'shift':
                        critera.department =subRule.value;

                }

            }
            }
            Meteor.users.find(criteria);
        });
    })
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: i have a loop in which i need to collect different field , and at the end of the looop i want to have only one query with all the params i concated in the loop

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code with the loop, as it's a bit hard to follow without actual code?

Comment: Your question is a bit weird and unclear. Could you include your specific use-case and a code example as chridam suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern occurs a lot. You have a search form with multiple fields but the user can type into any of them. For example let's say you have a search form with `firstName`, `lastName`, and `company` filter and you want to find matching people. To build up the right query you would do the following:

```
var query = {};
var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
var company = $("company").val();
if ( firstName ) query.firstName = firstName;
if ( lastName ) query.lastName = lastName;
if ( company ) query.company = company;
var cursor = People.find(query);
```

If you're going to do this in a loop then every input field needs to have an id == the field name in the db (or alternatively a name ==  the field name).

```
var query = {};
$("input").each(function(i,el){
  if ( $(el).val() ) query[el.id] = $(el).val();
});
MyCollection.find(query);
```